# urlRequest() in as3 import in captivate5

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, adobe-captivate

I code in flash(as3) a list loader via urlRequest('data.xml') and it work nice when I compile it .

This flash file need to import in captivate 5 but it seem that the flash file didn't process the xml file once import into captivate.

With fiddler I can see the request to the xml file and seem to be ok (statut 200 ok) but flash didnt display my data.

Someone have an hint to debug that issue?

Comment: you need to show some code or a project file.

Comment: I think you'll need to get or make a Captivate widget.